# DataTables -- Filter Table Data by Parameter given by URL

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatable

I know there are many other questions relating to this matter, but I have not found one that aligns quite fine with mine. I am working with angularjs, express, html, and jquery. I have a datatable structure that queries a folder for sub-directories, then has the ability to display the data within a selected sub-directory. The sub-directory nomenclature is the id of a client, and the data in the sub-directory are documents. On the page that the datatable is on, I have sent a parameter in this format : `domain/client/:id`. On the angular side, I have been able to capture this parameter and filter other results. But, I am not so sure how to in my Datatable. I do know how to filter the results of display in the datatable, that is not the issue. The issue is capturing this parameter and then passing it to my filter function. Here is the code for my datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $(".linksholder").dataTable({
        "fnCreatedRow": function(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
            if (!aData.IsDirectory) return;
            var path = aData.Path;
            $(nRow).bind("click", function(e) {
                $.get('/files?path=' + path).then(function(data) {
                    table.fnClearTable();
                    table.fnAddData(data);
                    currentPath = path;
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        },
        "aoColumns": [{
            "sTitle": "",
            "mData": null,
            "bSortable": false,
            "sClass": "head0",
            "sWidth": "55px",
            "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
                if (data.IsDirectory) {
                    return "<a href='#' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name + "</a>";
                } else {
                    return "<a href='/assets/" + data.Path + "' target='_blank'><i class='fa " + "'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name + "</a>";
                }
            }
        }],
    });
    $.get('/files').then(function(data) {
        table.fnClearTable();
        table.fnAddData(data);
    });
    $(".up").bind("click", function(e) {
        if (!currentPath) return;
        var idx = currentPath.lastIndexOf("/");
        var path = currentPath.substr(0, idx);
        $.get('/files?path=' + path).then(function(data) {
            table.fnClearTable();
            table.fnAddData(data);
            currentPath = path;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You should make this a directive and then you'll be able to pass your parameter to it via `scope` and an attribute on the directive. There are lots of posts on here about using jQuery with a directive in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

I added these variables:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var id = document.location.href.split('client/')[1];
```

Then called the specific sub-directory like this:

```
 $.get('/files?path=' + id).then(function(data) {
          table.fnClearTable();
          table.fnAddData(data);

        });
```